# Texmaker and moderncv with TeX Live 2011

Tags: texlive, texmaker, moderncv

I'm trying to do my CV with `moderncv` but Texmaker show me an error

```
!LaTeX Error:File 'moderncv.cls' not found.
```

But the `moderncv` macro is installed in TeX Live 2011.

Comment: from a terminal, do `sudo mktexlsr` to update the files database, and then `kpsewhich moderncv.cls`, just to check that it is correctly installed.

Comment: Also, `which tex` or `which kpsewhich` to be sure that the correct TeX Live installation is in use, in case you have two (eg, one installed by yourself, and one installed by your linux distro as a dependency to another package).

Comment: And for Windows? I use windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Comment: @Vassilis MiKTeX or TeX Live? For TL, you can start a Command Prompt with admin rights and proceed as for Linux (without `sudo`, of course). For MiKTeX, you are probably better using the graphical tools: update the Filename Data Base from the 'admin' version of the settings manager.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

**On Linux** From a Terminal, type `sudo mktexlsr` to update the files database, and then `kpsewhich moderncv.cls`, just to check that it is correctly installed.

**On Windows** For TeX Live, you can start a Command Prompt with admin rights and proceed as for Linux (without `sudo`, of course). For MiKTeX, you are probably better using the graphical tools: update the Filename Database from the 'admin' version of the settings manager.

Comment: when I tried to do from a terminal,mktexlsr to update the files database, and kpsewhich moderncv.cls,I got this error: starting package maintenance... installation directory: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9 package repository: http://ftp.uniRoma2.it/TeX/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ lightweight database digest: cb165a1c18f8d7e97d99f5d594be9dd3 going to download 890787 bytes going to install 24 file(s) (1 package(s)) downloading http://ftp.uniRoma2.it/TeX/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/moderncv.tar.lzma... kpsewhich: Couldn't connect to server what Should I do and thanks

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the moderncv from

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv

and copied the folder into

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/
```

Then I ran the following terminal command:

```
> sudo texhash
```

to let LaTeX know about the new folder in the file system.

Running my moderncv file again in my favorite LaTeX editor 'texmaker' is showed up properly. :)