# How to point miktex to load a moderncv template

Tags: pdftex, miktex, moderncv

My question is related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51361/texmaker-and-moderncv-with-tex-live-2011) one. I have run **mktexlsr** from a command prompt as administrator and the operation completed successfully. But when I try to compile the CV into a .pdf the following error is thrown:

```
    ! LaTeX Error: File `moderncv.cls' not found.

I have already downloaded moderncv into a separate directory. How can I point miktex to it?

The full miktex log is as follows:

    ======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: fd7a40a42ed2f1e70be3b6bdb1baccf2
going to download 1177267 bytes
going to install 38 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/moderncv.tar.lzma...

Unfortunately, the package moderncv could not be installed.Please check the log file:
C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log
======================================================================

! LaTeX Error: File `moderncv.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:
```

Comment: I guess you should stop the compiler before installing.

Comment: I did. I actually closed miktex, ran mktexlsr and then restarted it (miktex).

Comment: Did you install moderncv with MiKTeX  Package Manager?

Comment: Yes. I've got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix it. There is a long list of packages needed to be installed before compiling a cv using the **moderncv** template. All packages can be installed using the miktex package manager which on windows is installed by default in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\mpm_mfc_admin.exe
```

First, install **moderncv**. Installing manually is more of a [hassle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows). Upon compiling the CV many additional packages will be required by moderncv. One of them is **xparse.sty** which can be installed as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87402/using-mdframed-cant-install-xparse-sty) (install packages **l3kernel** and **l3packages**). Always make sure that miktex is [closed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18144/miktex-2-8-update-error-windows-api-error-87) while installing/updating packages. The next package which may raise difficulties is **tikz.sty** which requires packages **pgf** and **ms**. If all goes well, the CV should compile.